# Discord Python Script - Issues with scheduling Daily post on connected servers

Tags: python, datetime, discord, python-asyncio, discord.py

Computer: MacOS w/ Python 3.7 and Discord package installed

Server: CentOS 6 with Python 3.6 and Discord package installed

I'm thinking maybe the code is bad or can be optimized to clear the issue.

````
class MyClient(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Logged on as {0}!'.format(self.user))
        print(self.user.id)
        print('------')
        # loops through connected servers and assigns increments server count variable
        server_count = 0
        quote_count = 0
        for guild in client.guilds:
            server_count += 1
        print("The server count is {}".format(server_count))
        for quote in quotes:
            quote_count += 1
        print("There number of quotes available is: " + str(quote_count))
        print('------')
        while not client.is_closed():
            now = datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), '%H:%M')
            iter_count = 0
            print("current time is: " + now)
            if now == wakeup_time:  # enter for-loop at specific time
                for guild in client.guilds:
                    for channel in guild.channels:
                        if str(channel) == 'chat':
                            await channel.send('Good Morning/Afternoon/Good Night. Here is today\'s random quote:')
                            await channel.send('```' + str(random.choice(quotes)).strip('[]') + '```')
                            print("{} Server Greeted.").format(guild.name)
                            iter_count += 1
                            if iter_count == server_count:
                                await asyncio.sleep(7200)  # puts loop on hold for 1 hour
            else:
                await asyncio.sleep(10)
````

**What it's doing locally:** Posting to the #chat channel on each discord server one-time, then sleeping the function for 2 hours.  The bot is connected to four discord servers. (this is what I want it to do).

**What it's doing on the CentOS Linux server:** posting to the #chat channel of only one of the servers 5 times and then sleeping the function for two hours.

Question: is there a better way to optimize the code to loop through servers and post in the in the chat channels once per morning?

Comment: Just to clarify, this is working on your local clone, but not on the CentOS server?

Comment: Correct. I'm sure it can be written more efficiently, as I am new to this. But I am curious as to why it would not be doing the same thing in both environments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I would use a background task for this. Also, instead of using `guild.channels` use `guild.text_channels`. I've made a few changes to the code, hopefully this helps.

````
class MyClient(discord.Client):
    async def start_task(self):
        while not client.is_closed():
            now = datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), '%H:%M')
            iter_count = 0
            print("current time is: " + now)
            if now == wakeup_time:  # enter for-loop at specific time
                for guild in client.guilds:
                    for channel in guild.text_channels:
                        if channel.name == 'chat':
                            await channel.send('Good Morning/Afternoon/Good Night. Here is today\'s random quote:')
                            await channel.send('```' + str(random.choice(quotes)).strip('[]') + '```')
                            print("{} Server Greeted.").format(guild.name)
                            iter_count += 1
                            if iter_count == server_count:
                                await asyncio.sleep(7200)  # puts loop on hold for 1 hour
                            break
            else:
                await asyncio.sleep(10)

    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Logged on as {0}!'.format(self.user))
        print(self.user.id)
        print('------')
        # loops through connected servers and assigns increments server count variable
        quote_count = 0
        print("The server count is {}".format(len(client.guilds)))
        for quote in quotes:
            quote_count += 1
        print("There number of quotes available is: " + str(quote_count))
        client.loop.create_task(start_task())
````